# Perform function on a matrix based on values in another matrix

Tags: r, function

**Background:**

I have two matrices:

m contains various values for 10 different id's and a series of 10 months

m1 contains the information for whether the values should be considered or not

**Question:**

Is it possible to perform a function  on matrix *m* based on whether there is a value in *m1* ?

The function I would like to apply is the cumulative sum for 3 months (columns) of data in m.

i.e. id 3 (row 3) in matrix m, column 2 (1995-03-31) i would like to add the values -1.03208366 + 0.02686119 + -0.04857921 and store the answer in column 5 (1995-06-30)

Similarly for id 3 in matrix m column 3 i would like to add 0.02686119 + -0.04857921 + -0.21067198 and store the value in column 6 (1995-06-30)

**Data:**

```
set.seed(21)

m = matrix(rnorm(1:100), ncol=10) 

m1 = matrix(rep(NA,100), ncol=10)  

col.n = c('1995-02-28','1995-03-31','1995-04-28','1995-05-31','1995-06-30',
          '1995-07-31','1995-08-31','1995-09-29','1995-10-31','1995-11-30')

rownames(m) = rownames(m1) = 1:10

colnames(m) = colnames(m1) = col.n

m1[3,2]=m1[6,6]=m1[9,4]=m1[2,7]=m1[3,3]=1
```

Thanks in advance.